# perl script does not fully run when executed via php

Tags: php, perl

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why executing my perl script through the command line works great, but when I try to execute it through php, it runs the script, but fails at certain points.

```
OS: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
PHP Version: 5.3.3
Perl Version: 5.10.1
lighttpd Version: 1.4.39

web server type: lighttpd
webpage location: /var/www/htdocs/
scripts location: /var/www/htdocs/scripts/
jquery location: /var/www/htdocs/js/
```

JQUERY to call php script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "scripts/check_lsps.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'id='+device_id,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
    $device_id = $_POST['id'];
    $output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/perl /var/www/htdocs/scripts/lsp_script.pl ' . $device_id);
    echo ($output);
?>
```

Perl Script Area of Failure:

```
sub main {
    my %lsp_list = ();  
    #look for any unreachable hosts in local database
    ping_devices();
}


sub ping_devices {
    print "Checking local databse for unreachable hosts:\n";
    my ($result) = database_queries('localhost','juniper_lsps','','',qq(select device_id, device_name from juniper_lsps.devices));
    if (scalar(@$result) > 0) {
        for my $host (@$result) {
            my $p = Net::Ping->new("icmp"); **<-SCRIPT FAILS HERE** 
            unless ($p->ping($host->{device_name}, 1)) {
                print "Deleting all data related to $host->{device_name}, device is unreachable\n";
                database_queries('localhost','juniper_lsps','','',qq(delete from juniper_lsps.devices where device_name = '$host->{device_name}'));
                database_queries('localhost','juniper_lsps','','',qq(delete from juniper_lsps.lsps where device_id = '$host->{device_id}'));
                database_queries('localhost','juniper_lsps','','',qq(delete from juniper_lsps.lsp_paths where device_id = '$host->{device_id}'));
                print "Deleting of data completed.\n";
            }
            print "Completed checking local database for unreachable hosts\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        print "There are currently no downed lsps recorded.\n";
        print "Completed checking local database for unreachable hosts\n";
    }

}
```

When I execute the script by clicking on a button on my web page, I am able to return the result of @$result (perl script in the ping_devices function), but the script fails when it reaches the Net::Ping portion of the script and dies.

It works perfectly fine via the command line, but dies short when executing it via php.

Maybe something I am missing with php settings, but I have absolutely no clue.

I can provide more details if needed.

**EDIT: Sorry about this.**

It turns out to be a permissions issue when the php script tries to run Net::Ping("icmp") and required root privileges.

```
-sh-4.1$ php check_lsps.php 
icmp ping requires root privilege at /var/www/htdocs/scripts/lsp_script.pl line 54.
Array
(
    [0] => Checking local databse for unreachable hosts:
)
```

This was fixed by editing the original exec() command in the php script to:

```
exec('sudo /usr/bin/perl /var/www/htdocs/scripts/lsp_script.pl ' . $device_id, $output);
```

Comment: What is the error message? I'm wondering if some of your environment variables get clobbered when exec'ing via PHP.

Comment: @stevieb - Actually that is what also confuses me about this, there are no errors!  No php, lighttpd, or perl errors when running it.

Comment: @jmg0880: So how have you established that *"the script fails when it reaches the Net::Ping portion of the script and dies"* and how have you isolated *"Perl Script Area of Failure"*?

Comment: don't use shell_exec. it doesn't give access to the exec'd programs exit code, so there's NO way to tell between a program that failed, and one that simply has no output. use `exec()` instead, and add in the two extra parameters for exit code and output.

Comment: all that pearl could simply be rewritten in php, mixing languages like this is never a good idea

Comment: @Borodin - essentially when the script is executed via php, the return value I am getting is "checking local database for unreachable hosts", and if i dump the data in $result, I get the output of result.

If I try to get output past the Net::Ping statement, it fails.

Comment: @MarcB - funny thing is, I am getting a return value of "checking local database for unreachable hosts", but the script then dies as if it completed.  I also just tried to use exec and getting similar results. 

`exec('/usr/bin/perl /var/www/htdocs/scripts/lsp_script.pl ' . $device_id, $output);`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a permissions issue when the php script tries to run Net::Ping("icmp") and required root privileges.

```
-sh-4.1$ php check_lsps.php 
icmp ping requires root privilege at /var/www/htdocs/scripts/lsp_script.pl line 54.
Array
(
    [0] => Checking local databse for unreachable hosts:
)
```

This was fixed by editing the original exec() command in the php script to:

```
exec('sudo /usr/bin/perl /var/www/htdocs/scripts/lsp_script.pl ' . $device_id, $output);
```

- jmg0880